# Informix SQL — error in CASE statement

Tags: informix

I have a problem with Informix SQL syntax.

This is my SQL syntax

```
sql = "SELECT MONTH(startdatetime) MONTH, COUNT(sessionid) TotalCallsOffered, "+

      " CASE" +
      " WHEN MONTH(startdatetime) = 5" +
      " THEN 'SUSUKUDA' " +
      " END " +

      "FROM agentconnectiondetail a WHERE MONTH(startdatetime) = 5 " +
      "GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1 ASC";
```

and the output is

```
ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix] The column ((expression))
must be in the GROUP BY list.
```

What must I do?

Comment: Hi Harits, if the Jonathan answer give to you the way to found the correct soluction, please, check they answer as correct... or post the answer your self and check it... (you can do this too). Put the answer at the question is a nonstandard of stackexchange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Informix follows the strict SQL standard and requires all non-aggregate values in the select list to be listed in the GROUP BY clause.  Thus, the SQL must look like:

```
SELECT MONTH(startdatetime) AS Month, COUNT(sessionid) AS TotalCallsOffered,
       CASE
       WHEN MONTH(startdatetime) = 5
       THEN 'SUSUKUDA'
       END AS Susukuda
  FROM agentconnectiondetail
 WHERE MONTH(startdatetime) = 5
 GROUP BY Month, Susukuda
 ORDER BY Month ASC
```

I've chosen to name all three columns with AS and to GROUP BY those names (and ORDER BY them too).

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved with this

```
SELECT MONTH(startdatetime) AS Month, COUNT(sessionid) AS TotalCallsOffered,
       CASE
       WHEN MONTH(startdatetime) = 5
       THEN 'SUSUKUDA'
       END AS Susukuda
  FROM agentconnectiondetail
 WHERE MONTH(startdatetime) = 5
 GROUP BY 1, 3
 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: If you do this often, you will be unpopular.  Your 'accepted' self-answer is practically identical the previously accepted answer (you've used numbers instead of names in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY columns) with no explanation for why you have changed your mind about what is the correct answer.